# C: Using always widest type available would result in faster execution?

Tags: c, performance

Assuming that

1. memory occupation is not relevant
2. there is no need to allocate very large arrays (the biggest array count 1.000.000 elements).
3. the platform is 64 bit

Using always the widest type available for each variable:

---

`int64_t` for signed integers

`uint64_t` for unsigned integers

`double` for floating point numbers

---

would result in faster execution than using smaller types when 64 bits are not needed ?

Or would execute at the same speed (or slower) and occupy more memory?

Comment: There is a reason the C standard does not enforce a specific size for the standard types. Also note that on a 64 bit platform with a full set of load/store instructions for all data-sizes like x86 and ARMv8, there is normally no penalty using smaller types. But they consume less cache space. If you need the fastest type with a minimum guaranteed bit-width, use `(u)intNfast_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a game programmer, and frequently see people advocating double or floats.

Basically what I learned is: using the expected size by the hardware, is "usually" the faster, for example if the hardware expects a 64bit integer to do integer math, 64bit is faster.

The "double" camp defenders tend to use that argument only.

The problem is that for some software, you might hit other hurdles, like running out of cache, running out of pipelines (maybe the hardware can make out of order or parallel executions if the data is smaller than what it fits in its registers for example), explicit parallel operations (MMX, SSE, etc...), the amount of data that must be moved around in context switches, core switches and whatnot.

So the best "solution" I found, is to write some test code, run it in the designed hardware, and analyze the results.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Memory occupation affects performance so it could be the case that the 64 bit values compute faster than the 32 bit values, but because you can fit more 32 bit data on a cache line, the 32 bit data types may go faster anyway. The only way to know is test the particular algorithm on the particular hardware you are running it on.  Complicating things further are SIMD data types, which are even wider, and generally even faster as you can do 4, 8, or 16 operations at a time, assuming it is possible to efficiently implement your algorithm using them.

Answer (score 1):

One example not yet mentioned: on x86-64, there is a full range of instructions for 64-bit operands: load, store, arithmetic, etc.  However, in many cases, these instructions are *longer*.

For instance, `add ebx, eax`, which does a 32-bit add, is 2 bytes.  To do a 64-bit add, `add rbx, rax` is 3 bytes.

So even if they execute at the same speed, the 64-bit instructions will occupy more memory.  In particular, less of your code will fit in cache at any one time, potentially leading to more cache misses and slower speed overall.  So this is another reason not to explicitly demand 64-bit integers if you don't need them.

Comment: I actually did not say that! A "full set of ..." means there are instructions to load any size (8/16/32/64)  with zero- or sign-extend and stores for all these sizes, too. Also the number of instruction words does not necessarily mean it executes slower. x86 for instance converts the x86 codes to internal RISC instructions with fixed size anyway (it is the by far most complex CPU architecture).

Comment: @Olaf: Sorry.  I took out the attribution to you.

Comment: Your answer is x64-specific. On other architectures the smaller loads/stores might take more words. Most of them operate on 64 bit registers only and just load/store in smaller portions. You picture is far too narrow for a correct answer. Not sure if ARMv8 already outnumbers x64, but that will eventually happen within 1-2 years.

Comment: @Olaf: I thought I made it quite clear that it was an *example* of a *specific* architecture in which using the widest type is not necessarily faster.  The question asked if using the widest type was always faster; one example is sufficient to demonstrate that this is not always true.  But please feel free to share further information in your own answer!